# Responsive, Multi-Level Navigation IE7 Bug

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, multi-level

I'm using the sample code on this page to create a **responsive multi-level navigation**.
The example code **found here**:  ***[click here](http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/378_tessa/tessa-lt-dropdowns-21c7868/index.html)***  works great in IE7

However, my version located here: **[click here](http://sccsa.kook.com.au/)**  does not.

here is my **CSS**

```
#mainMenu ul{ margin:0; padding: 0; }
    nav { overflow: visible!important; }
    .nav { list-style: none;  *zoom: 1; background: transparent url('../images/background-pattern.jpg') repeat bottom center; }
    .nav:before, .nav:after { content: " ";  display: table; }
    .nav:after { clear: both;}
    .nav ul { list-style: none;  width: 12em; }
    .nav a { color:#aaa; line-height: 3em; padding:0 .9em 0 .9em; text-transform:uppercase; font-size: 90% }
    .nav a:hover, .nav li:hover > a{ color:#fff; }
    .nav li {  position: relative; }
    .nav > li { float: left;  }
    .nav > li > .parent { background-image: url("../images/downArrow.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right;}
    .nav > li > a { display: block;}
    .nav li ul { position: absolute;  left: -9999px;}
    .nav > li.hover > ul { left: 0; top: 0;}
    .nav li li.hover ul { left: 100%; top: 0;}
    .nav li li a { display: inline-block; /* For IE 7 and below, but anyone can see it */}
    .nav li li a { display: block; background: #2b2c2d; position: relative; z-index:100; border-top: 1px solid #1e1f20; line-height:1.6em; padding:0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.5em; text-transform:uppercase;}
    .nav li li li a { background:#353637; z-index:200; border-top: 1px solid #1e1f20;}
    .nav li li a:hover { background: #1e1f20; }
```

I've searched til I'm blue in the face but can't find out why?????????????

Comment: UPDATE: Came in Fresh this morning and fixed this.
There was some old code causing a conflict which has been removed.